# 'XML5619: Incorrect document syntax. ' error in IE10 Only

Tags: xml, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I've been noticing during some IE10 testing that I keep running into the following error:

```
XML5619: Incorrect document syntax.
```

However, I'm not using XML explicitly, and I can't seem to find documentation as to what this error actually means. I'm using the HTML5 doctype, if that matters.

Can anyone out there with IE expertise help lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

set the content-type of you're request to `text/xml` and the error will disappear.

I think IE10 expects the content-type to be set. Check Developer tools -> Network -> Start capturing what type your request is.

For `Ext.Ajax.request` set the content-type to `application/json`.

Answer (score 1):

> XML5619: Incorrect document syntax.

Above issue throws in IE because the **Content-Type** wont be there in the response header. To cross check the same, Open Developer Tools >Network check Content-Type for the request that will be black. IE expect Content-Type for every response data. To solve this issue set the content type for the response